# Grpc не отправляет ответное сообщение

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc

У меня есть Grpc-сервис, который получает во входном сообщении email и пароль пользователя, потом отправляет в ответ авторизационный токен (пока просто закодированную строку). Но когда я проверяю этот запрос в Postman, мне ничего не возвращается. Кто знает, в чем может быть проблема?
**Код сервиса**

```
public class AuthService : AuthRequest.AuthService.AuthServiceBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<AuthService> _logger;

    public AuthService(ILogger<AuthService> logger) => _logger = logger;

    
    public override Task<TokenData> Login(LoginData request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Got login request: {request}");
        return Task.FromResult(new TokenData() { Token = "123" });
    }
}
```

**Подключение сервиса**

```
public override void ConfigureApplication(WebApplication app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoint => endpoint.MapGrpcService<AuthService>());
    }

public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration) => services.AddGrpc();
```

**Proto-файл**

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "AuthRequest";

package auth;

service AuthService {
  rpc Login (LoginData) returns (TokenData);
}

message LoginData {
  string email = 1;
  string password = 2;
}

message TokenData {
  string token = 1;
}
```

**csproj-файл**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Automapper" Version="11.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="11.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="11.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.DependencyInjectionExtensions" Version="11.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="GitInfo" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.21.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Grpc.AspNetCore" Version="2.47.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.47.0">
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="10.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="10.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.0.6" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.6" />
        <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.AspNetCore" Version="3.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.3.1" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Facade.Infrastructure\Facade.Infrastructure.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Protobuf Include="Protos\auth.proto" GrpcService="Server" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: gRPC - это модифицированный HTTP/2, вы уверены что ваша версия Postman поддерживает gRPC? Поддержка этого протокола в Postman появилась совсем недавно.

Comment: Уверен, тк на другом проекте он спокойно отправлял и принимал grpc запросы